# Error in my query code at the right syntax to use near .. ' 'paid')' PHP

Tags: php

i still can't fish out the problem here with my code, am trying to insert my form data in my mysql database and my query is giving me error. All database field except the 'patient_name' and 'payment status' and the 'payment date' is int but am still getting error anytime i submit the query

'QUERY FAILED You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'paid')'

can't still understand what's wrong in the code

My Query :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO payment (
      patient_name,
      payment_date,
      consult_charge,
      medicine_charge,
      blood_report,
      injection_charge,
      xray_charge,
      total_charge,
      payment_status) VALUES(
      '$patient_name',
      now(),
      $consult_charge,
      $medicine_charge,
      $blood_report,
      $injection_charge,
      $xray_charge,
      $total_charge,
      'paid')";
```

My Html Code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<select class="custom-select" name="patient_name">
  <option selected value="" >Select Patient</option>
  <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patient_query_result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['surname'] .' '.$row['names']; ?>"><?php echo $row['surname'] .' '.$row['names']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>

<label for="consult_charge">Consulting Charge </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="consult_charge" name="consult_charge">

<label for="medicine_charge">Medicine Charge </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="medicine_charge" name="medicine_charge">

<label for="blood_report">Blood Report </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="blood_report" name="blood_report">

<label for="injection_charge">Injection Charge</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="injection_charge" name="injection_charge">

<label for="xray_charge">X-Ray </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="xray_charge" name="xray_charge">

<label for="total_charge">Total </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_charge" name="total_charge" readonly>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>

</form>
```

Comment: It's likely that all of your values are strings and therefore need to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: remove '' around paid

Comment: add \" \" around paid

Comment: That's wrong @SanthoshKumar as *paid* is a string.

Comment: @JayBlanchard adding \" around paid?

Comment: paid is suppose to be string

Comment: Not needed @SanthoshKumar, the rest of the values are strings and should be quoted. *paid* is not the actual issue.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is that neccesssary the 'payment status field in the database is varcharr'

Comment: @JayBlanchard the rest value is suppose to be int

Comment: How would we know that @funintellect? You didn't give us a description of your database.

Comment: *:he 'payment date' is int "*? Uh, no. That should be a datetime field if you're using `NOW()` to populate it.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, your values should be in single quote. You skipped after now() function.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO payment (
      patient_name,
      payment_date,
      consult_charge,
      medicine_charge,
      blood_report,
      injection_charge,
      xray_charge,
      total_charge,
      payment_status) 
      VALUES(
      '$patient_name',
      now(),
      '$consult_charge',
      '$medicine_charge',
      '$blood_report',
      '$injection_charge',
      '$xray_charge',
      '$total_charge',
      'paid')";
```

Comment: silly of me, i taught since the field in the database is int, i don't need to quote it...thanks

Comment: Your input fields for those numbers are `type="text"` so what did you think they would be sent as @funintellect? You have to cast them to INT of you want to have INT's in the database.